# How to apply the same function to several variables in R?

Tags: r, function, for-loop, lapply

I know that similar questions have already been asked (e.g. [Passing list element names as a variable to functions within lapply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094279/passing-list-element-names-as-a-variable-to-functions-within-lapply) or [R - iteratively apply a function of a list of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31800615/r-iteratively-apply-a-function-of-a-list-of-variables)), but I couldn't manage to find a solution for my problem based on these posts.

I have an event dataset (~100 variables, >2000 observations) that contains variables with information on the involved actors. One variable can only contain one actor, so if several actors have been involved in the event, they are spread over several variables (e.g. *actor1*, *actor2*, ...). These actors can be classified into two groups ("s" and "nons"). For later use, **I need two lists of actors**: one that contains all actors of the category "s" and one that contains all actors of "nons". "s" only consists of three actors while "nons" consists of dozens of actors.

```
# create example data
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:8),
                 actor1 = c("A", "B", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", NA),
                 actor2 = c("A", NA, "B", "C", "E", "I", "D", "G"))

df <-  
  df %>%
  mutate(actor1 = as.character(actor1),
         actor2 = as.character(actor2))
```

Since the script I am about to prepare is supposed to be used on updated versions of the dataset in the future, I would like to automate as much as possible and keep the parts of the script that would need to be adapted as limited as possible. My idea was to create one function per category that extracts the actors of the respective category (e.g. "nons") from one variable (e.g. *actor1*) in a list and then "loop" this function over the other variables (ideally with the *apply* family).

I know which category each actor belongs to ("A", "B", and "C" are category "s"), which allows me to define a separation rule as used in the function below (the *filter* command).

```
# create function
nons_function <- function(col) {
  col_ <- enquo(col)
  nons_list <-
    df %>%
    filter(!is.na(!!col_), !!col_ != "A", !!col_ != "B", !!col_ != "C") %>%
    distinct(!!col_) %>%
    pull()
  nons_list
}

# create list of variables to "loop" over
actorlist <- c("actor1", "actor2")
```

This results in the following. Instead of two lists of actors I get a list that contains the variable names as character strings.

```
> lapply(actorlist, nons_function)
[[1]]
[1] "actor1"

[[2]]
[1] "actor2"
```

What I would like to get is something like the following:

```
> lapply(actorlist, nons_function)
[[1]]
[1] "D" "E" "F" "G" "H"

[[2]]
[1] "E" "I" "D" "G"
```

The problem is probably the way I am passing the variable names to my function within *lapply*. Apparently, my function is not able use a character input as variable names. However, I have not found a way to either adapt my function in a way that allows for character input or to provide my function with a list of variables to loop over in a way it can digest.

Any help appreciated!

**EDIT:** Initially I had named the actors in a misleading way (actor names indicated which category an actor belongs to), which lead to answers that do not really help in my case. I have changed the actor names from "s1", "s2", "nons1", "nons2" etc to "A", "B", "C" etc now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
map(actorlist, ~ df %>% 
                  select(.x) %>%
                  filter(!str_detect(!! rlang::sym(.x), "^s\\d+$")) %>% 
                   pull(1))
#[[1]]
#[1] "nons1" "nons2" "nons3" "nons4" "nons5"

#[[2]]
#[1] "nons2" "nons6" "nons1" "nons4"
```

It can be wrapped as a function as well.  Note that the input is string, so instead of `enquo`, use `sym` to convert to symbol and then evaluate (`!!`)

```
f1 <- function(dat, colNm) {
                dat %>%
                  select(colNm) %>%
                   filter(!str_detect(!! rlang::sym(colNm), "^s\\d+$")) %>%
                    pull(1) %>%
                    unique
         }

map(actorlist, f1, dat = df)
```

NOTE: This can be done more easily, but here we are using similar code from the OP's post

---

Another option is to use `split` with `grepl` in `base R` and that returns a `list` of both 'nons' and 's' after removing the `NA`s

```
lapply(df[2:3], function(x)  {
           x1 <- x[!is.na(x)]
            split(x1, grepl("nons", x1))})
```

Comment: Using sym instead of enquo in my function solved the issue. Thanks a lot! But apart from that: Unfortunately I had named the variables in a misleading way for this example, which is why your filter does not work in my case (see the EDIT of my post). But since I really like your first option: What would the filter have to look like to filter "A", "B" and "C" from the other actor names (excluding NAs)?

Comment: @MarkusG It is based on the regex pattern `"s"` followed by one or more numbers (`\\d+`).  In the edit, it is not the case.  You can use `%in%` with `!` (negate) i..e `map(actorlist, ~ df %>% select(.x) %>% filter(!(!! rlang::sym(.x) %in% c('A', 'B', 'C')) ) %>% na.omit %>% pull() )`

Comment: Thank you very much! That does the job

Answer (score 2):

here is an option using base r.

for nons-actors:

```
lapply( df[, 2:3], function(x) grep( "^nons", x, value = TRUE ) )

#$actor1
#[1] "nons1" "nons2" "nons3" "nons4" "nons5"
#
#$actor2
#[1] "nons2" "nons6" "nons1" "nons4"
```

and for s-actors:

```
lapply( df[, 2:3], function(x) grep( "^s", x, value = TRUE ) )

# $actor1
# [1] "s1" "s2"
# 
# $actor2
# [1] "s1" "s2" "s3"
```

Comment: Simple solution, thanks! But since unfortunately I had named the variables in a misleading way for this example, filtering for name patterns with grep does not help me (see my EDIT).

Answer (score 0):

Check my solution and see if it works for you.

```
require("dplyr")


# create example data
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:8),
                 actor1 = c("s1", "s2", "nons1", "nons2", "nons3", "nons4", "nons5", NA),
                 actor2 = c("s1", NA, "s2", "s3", "nons2", "nons6", "nons1", "nons4"))

df <-  
  df %>%
  mutate(actor1 = as.character(actor1),
         actor2 = as.character(actor2))


# Function for getting the category
category_function <- function(col,categ){

  if(categ == "non"){
    outp = grep("^non",col,value = T)
  }else{
    outp = grep("^s",col,value = T)
  }

  return(outp)  

}

# Apply the function to all variables whose name starts with "actor"
sapply(df[grep("actor",names(df),value=T)],category_function,categ="non")
sapply(df[grep("actor",names(df),value=T)],category_function,categ="s")
```

My output was the following:

```
> sapply(df[grep("actor",names(df),value=T)],category_function,categ="non")
$actor1
[1] "nons1" "nons2" "nons3" "nons4" "nons5"

$actor2
[1] "nons2" "nons6" "nons1" "nons4"

> sapply(df[grep("actor",names(df),value=T)],category_function,categ="s")
$actor1
[1] "s1" "s2"

$actor2
[1] "s1" "s2" "s3"
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. It works for my example, but not for my real data because there 1) the actors are not named in a way that allows to deduct the category from the actor name (see the EDIT of my post) and 2) there are many more variables with "actor" in their name that contain different information. Therefore, using *grep* in the category function and later in the *sapply* call does not help.